# What are "getcited.org" and "getcited.com" for?

Tags: citations, literature

What is the purpose of getcited.org and getcited.com?

I am completely new to researching and paper publishing and I frequently get results from this site in Google Scholar Search.

I am absolutely not able to make out what this site does, it just gives the name of the paper, the author and the publication. It does not give a link to download them, neither does it give any abstract.

There are these *link buttons* which ask you to enter a username and password each time. Even after creating an account and logging in, I am asked to log in each time I click on a link button and the link button just opens my profile on the website.

Comment: I'm not going to make this a formal answer, since I know nothing about these sites except for what I've found by spending a few minutes looking.  However, I think they serve no useful purpose: poorly designed web pages, slow databases, not that much content.  GetCITED started in 2001 and may not have been maintained in recent years.  It was probably a good idea in 2001, but it didn't catch on and is no longer useful.  I'm surprised you frequently get search results from there, since I never do, but it probably depends on the topics.

Comment: (See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:GetCITED, http://www.archives.expressnews.ualberta.ca/article/2001/07/222.html.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the wikipedia page:

> GetCITED is a website database that lists publication and citation information on academic articles whose information is entered by members. It aims to include not only journal articles but also book chapters and other publications, both peer-reviewed and non-reviewed. The objective is to make this information publicly available, as such information is presently held in restricted databases. It indexes over 3,000,000 publications from over 300,000 authors.

However, on the actual getcited.org webpage, we see the copyright dates *2000-2006*, which makes me think the page has not been maintained in 5 or 6 years.  So basically, it seems to be a dead website, that is still available mainly because domain registration is so cheap.